# Is the purpose of the %d conversion specifier to verify that the argument consists exclusively of digit characters?

Tags: bash

```
printf "This is a number: %d\n" 10
> This is a number: 10
```

My understanding is that %d means: the argument is an integer. But the argument (10) isn't an integer, it's a string consisting of two characters: '1' and '0'. Is the purpose of %d to check the argument to ensure that the **string** consists exclusively of digit characters? Even though it's called a "conversion specification" there isn't any converting actually occurring, right?

Comment: The only data type in bash is the string (well, and an array of strings, if you count arrays). The %d specifer is used to reformat strings (for instance, **padding** it with spaces to a certain width, or **converting** a string containing the octal representation of an integer to a string holding the corresponding decimal one). As a side effect, it complains if the argument does not represent an integer number, so you **can** use it for checking as well. However, testing for the syntax of an integral number is perhaps easier done using a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell is not [C](https://man.cx/printf(3)). You cannot really pass a 32/64-bit integer to shell's `printf` which only accepts strings.

Bash's `printf` does report error on invalid inputs so it can be used to validate numbers:

```
$ printf '%d\n' abc
bash: printf: abc: invalid number
0
$ echo $?
1
$ printf '%d\n' 123abc
bash: printf: 123abc: invalid number
123
$ echo $?
1
```

But I think it's more useful when you want to print something in specific formats:

```
$ printf '%8d\n' 0x100
     256
$ printf '%#08x\n' 12345
0x003039
$ printf '%.2f\n' 123.456
123.46
```